# Getting and setting state in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, state

Here is some code from the Functional Programming in Scala book:

```
  import State._

  case class State[S, +A](run: S => (A, S)) {
    def map[B](f: A => B): State[S, B] =
      flatMap(a => unit(f(a)))

    def map2[B, C](sb: State[S, B])(f: (A, B) => C): State[S, C] =
      flatMap(a => sb.map(b => f(a, b)))

    def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = State(s => {
      val (a, s1) = run(s)
      f(a).run(s1)
    })
  }

  object State {
    type Rand[A] = State[RNG, A]

    def unit[S, A](a: A): State[S, A] =
      State(s => (a, s))

    // The idiomatic solution is expressed via foldRight
    def sequenceViaFoldRight[S, A](sas: List[State[S, A]]): State[S, List[A]] =
      sas.foldRight(unit[S, List[A]](List.empty[A]))((f, acc) => f.map2(acc)(_ :: _))

    // This implementation uses a loop internally and is the same recursion
    // pattern as a left fold. It is quite common with left folds to build
    // up a list in reverse order, then reverse it at the end.
    // (We could also use a collection.mutable.ListBuffer internally.)
    def sequence[S, A](sas: List[State[S, A]]): State[S, List[A]] = {
      def go(s: S, actions: List[State[S, A]], acc: List[A]): (List[A], S) =
        actions match {
          case Nil => (acc.reverse, s)
          case h :: t => h.run(s) match {
            case (a, s2) => go(s2, t, a :: acc)
          }
        }
      State((s: S) => go(s, sas, List()))
    }

    // We can also write the loop using a left fold. This is tail recursive like the
    // previous solution, but it reverses the list _before_ folding it instead of after.
    // You might think that this is slower than the `foldRight` solution since it
    // walks over the list twice, but it's actually faster! The `foldRight` solution
    // technically has to also walk the list twice, since it has to unravel the call
    // stack, not being tail recursive. And the call stack will be as tall as the list
    // is long.
    def sequenceViaFoldLeft[S, A](l: List[State[S, A]]): State[S, List[A]] =
      l.reverse.foldLeft(unit[S, List[A]](List()))((acc, f) => f.map2(acc)(_ :: _))

    def modify[S](f: S => S): State[S, Unit] = for {
      s <- get // Gets the current state and assigns it to `s`.
      _ <- set(f(s)) // Sets the new state to `f` applied to `s`.
    } yield ()

    def get[S]: State[S, S] = State(s => (s, s))

    def set[S](s: S): State[S, Unit] = State(_ => ((), s))
  }
```

I have spent hours thinking about why the `get` and `set` methods look the way they do, but I just don't understand.

Could anyone enlighten me, please?

Comment: Example added. Hopefully it clarifies even further

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is on the 3rd line:

```
case class State[S, +A](run: S => (A, S))
```

The stateful computation is expressed with the `run` function. This function represent a transition from one state `S` to another state `S`. `A` is a value we could produce when moving from one state to the other.

Now, how can we take the state `S` out of the state-monad? We could make a transition that doesn't go to a different state and we materialise the state as `A` with the function `s => (s, s)`:

```
def get[S]: State[S, S] = State(s => (s, s))
```

How to set the state? All we need is a function that goes to a state s: `??? => (???, s)`:

```
def set[S](s: S): State[S, Unit] = State(_ => ((), s))
```

---

**EDIT I would like to add an example to see `get` and `set` in action:**

```
val statefullComputationsCombined = for {
  a <- State.get[Int]
  b <- State.set(10)
  c <- State.get[Int]
  d <- State.set(100)
  e <- State.get[Int]
} yield (a, c, e)
```

Without looking further down this answer, what is the type of `statefullComputationsCombined`?

Must be a `State[S, A]` right? `S` is of type `Int` but what is `A`? Because we are yielding `(a, c, e)` must be a 3-tuple made by the `A`s of the `flatmap` steps (`<-`).

We said that `get` "fill" `A` with the state `S` so the `a, c ,d` are of type `S`, so `Int`. `b, d` are `Unit` because `def set[S](s: S): State[S, Unit]`.

```
val statefullComputationsCombined: State[Int, (Int, Int, Int)] = for ...
```

To use `statefullComputationsCombined` we need to `run` it:

```
statefullComputationsCombined.run(1)._1 == (1,10,100)
```

If we want the state at the end of the computation:

```
statefullComputationsCombined.run(1)._2 == 100
```